# Tensorflow: Object detection api error on google colab-no module named lvis

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run `'model_main_tf2.py'` in Tensorflow object detection on google colab.
Paths are alredy defined

```
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']+=":/content/gdrive/My Drive/TensorFlow_2/models"
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']+=":/content/gdrive/My Drive/TensorFlow_2/models/research"
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']+=":/content/gdrive/My Drive/TensorFlow_2/models/research/slim"
```

But i have an error

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/metrics/lvis_evaluation.py", line 23, in <module>
    from lvis import results as lvis_results
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lvis'
```

Answer (score 8):

It looks like your program is trying to `import results` from the package `lvis`
Make sure you have it installed, if you don't run

```
pip install lvis
```

in the command line

if you did install it and you still get this error i might be becuase it is not installed in the same python as the one you are trying to run your program with.
So in the command line type

```
pip list
```

to make sure you have lvis installed and then run you .py file (i think it's lvis_evaluation.py) from the command line and see if it works.